# How to add product metafields with ShopifyAPI in Python

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

I have no problem creating a product with ShopifyAPI, it gets tricky after product.save().

```
import shopify
# Configure store details
shop_url = 'store.myshopify.com'
admin_api_key = 'shpat_'
api_version = '2022-07'

# Create and activate a new session
session = shopify.Session(shop_url, api_version, admin_api_key)
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

# Create a new product Object, set the title
product = shopify.Product()
product.handle = "new-product"
product.title = "New product"
product.body_html = "Test description"
product.product_type = "Type"
product.vendor = "Vendor"
product.product_type = "Category"
product.tags = "Tag"
product.price = "9.99"
product.weight = "1.0"
product.weight_unit = 'kg'

variant = shopify.Variant({'sku': 'P1', 'price': 9.99, 'requires_shipping': True})
product.variants = [variant]

# Save the product object to Shopify
product.save()

# Add the metafield to the saved product object "product.metafields.custom.maker"
product.add_metafield(shopify.Metafield({
    'namespace':"custom",
    'key':"maker",
    'value':"Maker",
    'type':"string"
}))

# Save the updated product object to Shopify
product.save()
```

After product save, a new product shows in Shopify Backend.

A return of "metafield(None)" for the metafield part.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured this out, but posting to help others in case. The issue as I encountered as well is the correct definition of the type. Their API is lacking here a bit. While the type of 'string' is what you may expect to use, you actually have to use 'single_line_text_field' or whatever other specific type you defined. All submissions must be of the type 'string' and that's where I was confused at least.

Instead of:

```
    # Add the metafield to the saved product object 
   "product.metafields.custom.maker"
    product.add_metafield(shopify.Metafield({
    'namespace':"custom",
    'key':"maker",
    'value':"Maker",
    'type':"string"
     }))
```

Use:

```
# Add the metafield to the saved product object 
"product.metafields.custom.maker"
 product.add_metafield(shopify.Metafield({
'namespace':"custom",
'key':"maker",
'value':"Maker",
'type':"single_line_text_field"
}))
```

Comment: Thanks! That is subtle and annoying. 
In the case it helps others, the documentation on supported 'type'(s) are here

https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/custom-data/metafields/types